# Standard structure for multi-module java maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar, build, dependencies

Is there a standard or de facto structure for maven web application project which consist of multiple modules or child projects? Let's say I want to package my domain objects and integration utilities as a distinct jars to keep things modular and reusable. How should the folder structure look like and how I specify another build dependent of those jars that even doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven folks have a reference for that...

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-intro.html